# Template parse errors: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "cdkDropList"

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I am trying to use Angular Material for drag and drop as shown in [Transferring items between lists](http://Transferring%20items%20between%20lists).

I am trying the exact same code shown in the example but getting this error in console:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: There is
>   no directive with "exportAs" set to "cdkDropList"

Below is my code, its the same as shown in link, I am sharing anyways:

**TS:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

/**
 * @title Drag&Drop connected sorting
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example',
  templateUrl: 'cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.css'],
})
export class CdkDragDropConnectedSortingExample {
  todo = [
    'Get to work',
    'Pick up groceries',
    'Go home',
    'Fall asleep'
  ];

  done = [
    'Get up',
    'Brush teeth',
    'Take a shower',
    'Check e-mail',
    'Walk dog'
  ];

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                        event.container.data,
                        event.previousIndex,
                        event.currentIndex);
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="example-container">
  <h2>To do</h2>

  <div
    cdkDropList
    #todoList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="todo"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]"
    class="example-list"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="example-container">
  <h2>Done</h2>

  <div
    cdkDropList
    #doneList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="done"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todoList]"
    class="example-list"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of done" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As stated in the [API](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api) you need to import  `DragDropModule` in your module

```
import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    DragDropModule
    ...
```

Comment: Yeah, got it fixed a while ago, from another post

Comment: If the presented solution has worked for you, then other people with the same problem might find it useful too if you accept my answer or post and accept the solution that helped you

Comment: @Thanthu, please provide the other post.

Answer (score 1):

an extra answer for those new to angular world.
in angular Use the hash symbol (#) to declare a reference variable. The following reference variable, #phone, declares a phone variable on an  element.

```
<input #phone placeholder="phone number" />
```

A template reference variable is often a reference to a DOM element within a template. It can also refer to a directive (which contains a component), an element, TemplateRef, or a web component.
In most cases, Angular sets the reference variable's value to the element on which it is declared. but if you want to use a directive. it should be declared in reference variable value like below example

```
<form #itemForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(itemForm)">
  <label for="name"
    >Name <input class="form-control" name="name" ngModel required />
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

ngForm is a directive . and it should be known to angular compiler.
and in the question

```
<div
    cdkDropList
    #todoList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="todo"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]"
    class="example-list"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

cdkDropList is a directive too. therefore it should be known to compiler and therefore its module should be imported to the module it is used